# Setar campo como nulo - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Olá, beleza?

Estou fazendo um *update* em uma tabela e estou enviando o array de dados. Porem, eu tenho um campo de data. Toda vez que eu atualizo, ele manda o campo como `'dtnascimento' = ''`. Quando esse dado chega no banco de dados, o meu banco seta a data como `0000-00-00`.

O que eu desejo fazer: fazer uma verificação se o meu a posição do meu array está nulo. Se estiver nulo, setar para que o valor chegue no banco de dados como **(NULL)**.

Abaixo o meu código atual:

```
function atualizarFuncionario($dados){

    if ($dados['dtnascimento'] === '') {
        $dados['dtnascimento'] = NULL;
    }

    $where = array(
     'idfuncionario'    => $dados['idfuncionario'],
     'idempresa'        => $dados['idempresa']
    );
    $this->db->update($this->tabela,html_escape($dados),$where);

}
```

Se alguem souber, da uma moral ai rs

Comment: Não conseguido verificar se é null ou passar o valor `null` para o banco?

Comment: @rray ja tentei isso e acontece a mesma coisa que eu citei na segunda linha, `'dtnascimento' = ''`.

Comment: fiz uns testes com o PDO, gravou null quando eu passei `null` ou `'null'`, em branco ficou como `0000-00-00`

Comment: Altera o campo `data` para o formato date NULL, e quando você for adicionar, passe o campo como 'NULL' também

Answer (score 1):

Cara, pq tu não seta no Active Record quais os campos que tu quer atualizar?

Particularmente eu prefiro atualizar somente os dados específicos:

Supondo que tu vai atualizar somente o nome (que está preenchido) e o campo data, que tu não sabe se está preenchido...

```
$this->db-trans_begin();
$this->db->set('Nome', $dados['Nome']);
if($dados['dtnascimento'] != ''){
   $this->db->set('Data', $dados['dtnascimento']);
}
$this->db->where('idfuncionario', $dados['idfuncionario']);
$this->db->where('idempresa', $dados['idempresa']);
$this->db->update('tabela');
if($this->db->trans_status() === true){
   $this->db->trans_commit();
}else{
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
```

Desse modo, se o campo data não estiver preenchido, ele não altera nada...
Espero ter ajudado.
Oss!

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente eu uso o unset()

```
function atualizarFuncionario($dados){

    if ($dados['dtnascimento'] === '') {
        unset($dados['dtnascimento']);
    }

    $where = array(
     'idfuncionario'    => $dados['idfuncionario'],
     'idempresa'        => $dados['idempresa']
    );
    $this->db->update($this->tabela,html_escape($dados),$where);

}
```

Comment: Isso ai não vai matar a chave?

Comment: A verdade é que eu quero atualizar o campo, mas para nulo. Entendeu? Dessa forma, você nao vai atualizá-lo no banco de dados. Dessa forma você deixará o valor antigo se vc deixar o campo como **nulo**.

Comment: Hmm entendi!   Tentou usar $var = 'NULL'

Comment: Tentei sim, deu a mesma coisa que eu falei com o @rray ali em cima. Só que ele seta `'dtnascimento' = 'NULL'` e quando eu vou olhar no banco está `0000-00-00`.

Comment: Acho que é configuração do seu banco de dados...você está usando mysql?

Comment: Sim, Rafael. Estou usando o mysql